# How to Add Dropdown/selectbox inside JSON-EDITOR in angular

Tags: jquery, angular, angular6, angular8, angular9

I am using an angular JSON-editor for adding some fields int to my data.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ang-jsoneditor

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang-jsoneditor

This is my default JSON-Editor value:

`{ "color": { "property": 'Configurable', "Values": [] }, "material": { "property": 'Configurable', "Values": [] }, "size": { "property": 'Configurable', "Values": [] }}`

My requirement is needed to integrate a select box for the `property` attributes with some static values.

How can I included a Dropdown list inside the JSON-Editor.

Is there any option?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally  I got the answer,

```
    @ViewChild(JsonEditorComponent, { static: true }) editor: JsonEditorComponent;
    this.editorOptions = new JsonEditorOptions()
    this.editorOptions.modes = ['code', 'text', 'tree', 'view']; 
    this.editorOptions.expandAll = true;
    this.editorOptions.schema ={
  'definitions': {},
  '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
  '$id': 'http://example.com/root.json',
  'type': 'object',
  'title': 'Product Attributes',
  'required': [
    'property'
  ],
  'properties': {
    'property': {
      '$id': '#/properties/randomNumber',
      'type': 'string',
      'title': 'Attribute property',
      'default': 'Configurable',
      'examples': [
        'Configurable'
      ],
      'enum': ['Configurable','Simple']
    }
  }
}
```

I have added a JSON schema with the help of `new JsonEditorOptions()` and set the dropdown values using `Enum` keyword `'enum': ['Configurable','Simple']`. Now it will appear inside a select dropdown list.

And you can read the Json editor value in the `onChangeJSON`

```
  this.editorOptions.onChangeJSON = function () {
     const json = this.editor.get();   
     console.log(json);
  };
```